Unable to run a script in ProcessMaker
I'm working on dockerized version of ProcessMaker pm4core-docker and trying to run a script as part of a leave request process, what I want is that once an employee fills out his request and sends it, an email is automatically sent to the manager asking him to verify the request
Unable to create a docker container: Unable to find image 'processmaker4/executor-processmaker-php-3:v1.0.0' locally Error response from daemon: pull access denied for processmaker4/executor-processmaker-php-3, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied


Here is the PHP script I'm trying to run :
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host       = 'live.smtp.mailtrap.io';
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->Username   = 'api';
    $mail->Password   = '****************************';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
    $mail->Port       = 587;

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('noreply@demomailtrap.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('****************@gmail.com', 'Manager'); // Add a recipient

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'New leave request';
    $mail->Body    = 'Hello, you have a new leave request to review';
    $mail->AltBody = 'Hello, you have a new leave request to review';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}

And here is the error as mentioned previously :
Unable to create a docker container: Unable to find image 'processmaker4/executor-processmaker-php-3:v1.0.0' locally Error response from daemon: pull access denied for processmaker4/executor-processmaker-php-3, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied


Had the same issue, the whole dockerized version is super deprecated.
I had to update all dependencies in the docker.base file so i could build a newer version (4.11.5) of the processmaker image which should use the correct containers to download/build the script-executors.
